# How do I know what Microsoft account the skydrive app is syncing to?

Tags: onedrive

Some time ago, I set up skydrive for my wife on her mac. But now she wants to access the files online, I cannot remember what Microsoft account I setup and linked her skydive app to and nor can I see anything in the skydrive app settings to tell me either?

How can I see the name of the Microsoft account the skydive app is currently linked to?

I would like to know this for skydrive app for Mac and PC

Answer (score 0):

It only links back there if you are logged into the computer with the name attached to what you are looking at.  I apparently set on one OneDrive on one computer that is different than the one on my Windows 8.1 laptop, and I cannot find out the address I used for it either.  As I am on a Windows 7 desktop and when you go to manage storage you are taken to the website with the blank sign in information.  However from my Windows 8.1 when logged in there it does take me back to the correct sign in name online.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you may face situation when you cant make our which Microsoft account you're using with OneDrive. In such cases, you need to use Onedrive's unique CID. You can see the CID - a string of 16 hex digits - in several places; one is as the name of the .dat and .ini files in this folder:

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\s ettings\
For example, 375B34CD4FCBE487.
```

Once you've found out what the CID is, you can look up the account username - email address - in the registry.

Open Registry Editor (press Windows key + R, type regedit and press Enter) and navigate to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\U serExtendedProperties
```

If there is more than one email address listed, click on each in turn. Its associated CID will be given in the right-hand pane.

In this way, you can figure out exact account associated with OneDrive.

Comment: You've got some strange extraneous stuff in your answer.  The first part looks like it might be an attribution, although you don't link to the source.  The bold phrase at the end makes no sense.  You've put the body of the answer in a code block, but it looks like it might be a quote.  If you can clarify this, we can help you polish it into an answer that better fits the site's conventions.